# What's the best way to store & download dev .ipa files securely?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, ipa

Right now we've got an app and plenty of versions floating around on Dropbox, but I want to be able to store all IPAs securely yet keep them available so anyone within the company can download them directly to their iOS device. Originally we set up an S3 bucket with an ITMS tag to download, but that only enables storing one IPA per PLIST, whereupon a separate website has to host that link along with any release notes and known issues.

We tried moving to a secure wiki but that ended up being more work than simply overwriting the IPA (and never updating the PLIST). Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use OTA,  over the air distribution. It is a feature of xcode, basically you store your IPA files on your server (with the respective info.plist) and when you want to share the app you have only to share the url. Google it, you have to do some steps but is quite easy and absolutely secure (also because the device on which you want to download the app must be registered on your provisioning profile).